# Can I change which classes Bootstrap-generated tables are assigned?

Tags: html, css

How can I stop Bootstrap from assigning a class to a Bootstrap generated search field?

I have a bootstrap table in a .html template with data-search='true' set as a parameter.

```
<div class="usage-history-table">
<table id="historyTable" data-toggle="table" data-height="300" data-pagination="true" data-search="true" data-sort-name="starttime" data-sort-order="desc" data-page-list="[5, 10, 20, 50]" class="table-bordered" border='1'>
```

After it is rendered it creates my table with a search field above the table contents:

```
<div class="bootstrap-table"><div class="fixed-table-toolbar"><div class="pull-right search"><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search"></div>
```

I do not want the "pull-right" class to be applied to search fields automatically in my Bootstrap tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to remove that style?

Use jQuery removeclass method:

```
$(".bootstrap-table").removeClass("pull-right");
```

or you want to override the style? Follow this css code

```
.pull-right { padding: 10px 30px!important; top:37px!important;}
```

You can override predefined style by including `!important`

Comment: @marc_s thanks for your edit. I am new here and this is my first answer in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

It's always wise to spend a few more minutes reading the documentation that is availiable to us.

Accordingly to the documentation in:http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/

> "The table options are defined in jQuery.fn.bootstrapTable.defaults."

An the option that specifies the alignment is **searchAlign**
You can use "left" or "right", and the default option is "right".

Comment: Right - But the only options are to align it right or left, and is pretty limited.